# How many game systems does Steven own?

Tags: steven-universe

In episode 3 of *Steven Universe*, Steven is shown to have a system resembling a Nintendo 64 in his room. In later episodes, [he's also been shown to have a Nintendo GameCube](https://www.reddit.com/r/stevenuniverse/comments/34419a/steven_universe_paying_homage_to_the_one_and_only/).

**Has Steven been shown to own any other video game consoles? If so, which ones does he own?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Steven has been shown to have 3 systems; a *Nintendo 64*, *GameCube*, and *Game Boy*.**

---

### Nintendo 64

- Appears in [*Cheeseburger Backpack*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Cheeseburger_Backpack_(episode)) (S1 Ep3), [*Rose's Room*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Rose%27s_Room) (S1 Ep19), [*Gem Drill*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Gem_Drill) (S3 Ep2) and [*Mr. Greg*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Greg) (S3 Ep8).
- Games: [*Golf Quest Mini*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Golf_Quest_Mini) (Parody of various RPGs)

[image: Nintendo 64 playing Golf Quest Mini]

<sup>Image from [*Rose's Room*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Rose%27s_Room)</sup>

### Nintendo GameCube

- Appears in [*House Guest*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/House_Guest) (S1 Ep27), [*Lion 3: Straight to Video*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Lion_3:_Straight_to_Video#Objects) (S1 Ep35), [*Open Book*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Open_Book) (S1 Ep46), [*Say Uncle*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Say_Uncle) (S2 Ep3), [*Steven vs. Amethyst*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_vs._Amethyst) (S3 Ep19), and [*Steven Reacts*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Reacts) (iTunes)
- Referred to as "Dolphin" in [*Steven vs. Amethyst*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_vs._Amethyst) as a reference to the GameCube's development codename.
- The online short [*Steven Reacts*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Reacts) shows the games "Steel Cog", "Pikemen 2", "Star Battlers: Team Leader", "Lue's Estate", "Smash Pals Scuffle", and "Forever Darkness" on a shelf behind Steven

  - Referencing *Metal Gear Solid: Twin Snakes*, *Pikmin 2*, *Star Wars Rogue Leader*, *Luigi's Mansion*, *Super Smash Bros. Melee*, and *Eternal Darkness: Sanity's Requiem* respectively
- Games resembling *Animal Crossing* and *The Legend of Zelda: Wind Waker* can be seen on the floor of Steven's Room in [*Open Book*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Open_Book) (S1 Ep46)

[image: Nintendo GameCube in Steven's Room]
[image: Dolphin game collection on Steven's Shelf]

<sup>Images from [*Open Book*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Open_Book) and [*Steven Reacts*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Steven_Reacts)</sup>

### Nintendo Game Boy

- Appears in [*Catch and Release*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Catch_and_Release) (S2 Ep18)
- Located in Steven's Bathroom

[image: Game Boy in Steven's Bathroom]

<sup>Image from [*Catch and Release*](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Catch_and_Release)</sup>

---

#### Sources

- [Reddit - Steven Universe paying homage to the one and only Nintendo GameCube.](https://www.reddit.com/r/stevenuniverse/comments/34419a/steven_universe_paying_homage_to_the_one_and_only/)
- [Steven Universe Wiki - References in Steven Universe](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/References_in_Steven_Universe)
- [Steven Universe Wiki - Steven's Video Game Systems](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/Steven%27s_Video_Game_Systems)

Comment: for a moment there i though Dolphin was a reference to the Emulator but it's probably more likely the Emulator is named after the development codename

Comment: @Memor-X As a [past developer for Dolphin](https://bugs.dolphin-emu.org/users/3169), I can confirm that yes, Nintendo's codename came first. :P

Comment: How do you know the Game Boy is Steven's? Maybe one of the Crystal Gems sneaks into the bathroom to play on it. :-)